# What is the cause of `org.quartz.core.jobrunshell threw an unhandled exception` exception?

Tags: scala

what is the cause of `org.quartz.core.jobrunshell threw an unhandled exception`?

Exception:

```
Oct 18 23:30:03 ip-172-31-9-197 vendor-integrations:  ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell: Job DefaultGroup.SmashFly Sync Job threw an unhandled Exception: 
Oct 18 23:30:03 ip-172-31-9-197 vendor-integrations:  ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger: Job (DefaultGroup.SmashFly Sync Job threw an exception.
```

Also please suggest possible ways to handle it?

Comment: Feel like describing what it is you're doing...?

Comment: what libraries are involved here? you should probably add at least one tag besides just "scala"